# Is there a way to make Hubspot forms to send a unique identifier to a third-party software

Tags: javascript, api, hubspot

We are working with different affiliate partners. They send traffic to our pages generating free trial signups. We're currently using Hubspot CMS and Hubspot forms to collect the free trial signups.

The issue is attribution: Hubspot does not natively enable any integrations that would enable getting a “unique identifier” such as the email address to an affiliate marketing software.

Does anyone know any workarounds for this issue?

Hubspot is suggesting creating tracking / UTM links but that would mean loads of manual work with each affiliate. In other words, their suggestion does not scale.